# Destructuring declaration initializer of type ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, kotlin, objectanimator

I'm using kotlin destructuring declarations. I used it before with `SpringAnimation` and it worked perfectly. Now I want use it with `ObjectAnimator` and I get this error:

> Destructuring declaration initializer of type ObjectAnimator! must have a 'component1()' function
>
> Destructuring declaration initializer of type ObjectAnimator! must have a 'component2()' function

Here is my code:

```
val (xanimator, alphaanim) = findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView).let { img ->
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationX", 100f).apply {
                duration = 2000
            }
            to
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "alpha", 1.0f).apply {
                duration = 2000
            }
        }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Please check this once: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you can't start an infix call function call on a new line - the compiler essentially infers a semicolon/line ending after your first `apply` call. This is the same way with operators, [see this issue](https://github.com/android/kotlin-guides/issues/51) for example.

So you need to reformat your code a bit for the `to` to connect, most simply like this:

```
val (xanimator: ObjectAnimator, alphaanim: ObjectAnimator) = findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView).let { img ->
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationX", 100f).apply {
        duration = 2000
    } to
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "alpha", 1.0f).apply {
        duration = 2000
    }
}
```

But for readability, maybe you could go with something like this:

```
val (xanimator: ObjectAnimator, alphaanim: ObjectAnimator) = findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView).let { img ->
    Pair(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationX", 100f).apply {
                duration = 2000
            },
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "alpha", 1.0f).apply {
                duration = 2000
            }
    )
}
```

Or anything inbetween.